# How to scrape related category of element using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to webscrape this site https://bulkfollows.com/services
What I want is to get every service row which has features like this: `'ID',  'Service', 'Rate per 1000', 'Min / Max', 'Refill','Avg. Time','Description','category'` I got everything except category column a category column is a parent feature which is like these :

```
" YouTube - Watch Time By Length" or "Instagram - Followers [ From  ✓VERIFIED ACCOUNTS]"
```

This is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url="https://bulkfollows.com/services"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml") 

categories = dict((e.get('data-filter-category-id'),e.get('data-filter-category-name')) for e in soup.select('.dropdown-menu button[data-filter-category-name]'))

data= []
for e in soup.select("#serviceList tr:has(td)"):    
    d = dict(zip(e.find_previous('thead').stripped_strings,e.stripped_strings))
    d['category'] = categories[e.get('data-filter-table-category-id')] if e.get('data-filter-table-category-id') else None
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)[['ID',  'Service', 'Rate per 1000', 'Min / Max', 'Refill','Avg. Time','Description','category']]
```

I need some help in the for loop for getting parent columns
this is my output : [image]

I want the category column not none and the description when you click for example in first service I want it to be:

> > Link: https://youtube.com/video Start: 0-12hrs Speed: 100-200 Per day Refill: 30 days
>
> Please Note: Watch time will take 1-3 days to update on analytics.
> After 3 days of delivery, if the watch time does not update, please
> take a screenshot of your video analytic ( Not the Monetization page,
> we don't guarantee Monetization ) and upload it to prntscr.com and
> send it us the uploaded screenshot ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one fits all approach for scraping - So you have to select your elements more specific, may check the docs for some [finding strategies](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree).

Replace the line:

```
d['category'] = categories[e.get('data-filter-table-category-id')] if e.get('data-filter-table-category-id') else None
```

with following, that will take a look to previous `<h4>` to grab the `Category` and to the next modal to get the `Description`:

```
d['Category'] = e.find_previous('h4').get_text(strip=True)
d['Description'] = e.find('div',{'class':'modal-body'}).get_text(' ',strip=True)
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url="https://bulkfollows.com/services"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml") 

categories = dict((e.get('data-filter-category-id'),e.get('data-filter-category-name')) for e in soup.select('.dropdown-menu button[data-filter-category-name]'))

data= []
for e in soup.select("#serviceList tr:has(td)"):    
    d = dict(zip(e.find_previous('thead').stripped_strings,e.stripped_strings))
    d['Category'] = e.find_previous('h4').get_text(strip=True)
    d['Description'] = e.find('div',{'class':'modal-body'}).get_text(' ',strip=True)
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)[['ID',  'Service', 'Rate per 1000', 'Min / Max', 'Refill','Avg. Time','Description','Category']]
```

###### Output

|  | ID | Service | Rate per 1000 | Min / Max | Refill | Avg. Time | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7365 | YouTube - Subscribers ~ Max 120k ~ 30D ~ 500-2k/days ~ [ - , ] | $4.80 | 100 / 120000 | Refill 30 days | 59 hours 53 minutes | Link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYhvmzYNxCAGBaMhnsk69kg Start: Instant - 0 hrs Speed: 500-2k/day Refill: 30 days Drop: 0- 5% drop. | ❖ Bulkfollows High Demand Services |
| 1 | 7363 | Spotify - Plays ~ ~ 10k-50k/days ~ USA/Russian ~ [ - , ] | $0.188 | 1000 / 100000000 | Refill Lifetime | 22 hours 26 minutes | Link: https://open.spotify.com/track/40Zb4FZ6nS1Hj8RVfaLkCV Start: Instant ( Avg 0-3 hrs ) Speed: 10k to 20k days Refill: Lifetime Quality: Plays from Bot Created free accounts. Make sure you know the risk of adding of bot plays Drop: Spotify Plays are stable, do not drop. Delivery Time: It will take 2-5 days to update plays. If it's delivery 10k in 1 day, then this 10k will take 2-5 days to update, the next 10k plays will take the next 2-5 days, and so on. | ❖ Bulkfollows High Demand Services |
| 3973 | 7613 | Australia Traffic from Instagram | $0.025 | 100 / 1000000 | No Refill | Not enough data | Use a bit.ly link to track traffic ✅ 100% Real & Unique Visitors ✅ Google Analytics Supported Session Length: 40-60 Seconds per visit ⬇️ Bounce Rates: Low ⚡️ Speed: 10,000 unique visitors per day Start Time: 0-12h (we check all links for compliance) ️ Desktop Traffic Over 90% Mobile Traffic Under 10% ⚠️ No Adult, Drug or offensive websites allowed Link Format: Enter Full Website URL | ⚊ Website Traffic from Australia [ + Choose Referrer ] |
| 3974 | 7614 | Australia Traffic from Wikipedia | $0.025 | 100 / 1000000 | No Refill | Not enough data | Use a bit.ly link to track traffic ✅ 100% Real & Unique Visitors ✅ Google Analytics Supported Session Length: 40-60 Seconds per visit ⬇️ Bounce Rates: Low ⚡️ Speed: 10,000 unique visitors per day Start Time: 0-12h (we check all links for compliance) ️ Desktop Traffic Over 90% Mobile Traffic Under 10% ⚠️ No Adult, Drug or offensive websites allowed Link Format: Enter Full Website URL | ⚊ Website Traffic from Australia [ + Choose Referrer ] |

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, i really appreciate it . Can i ask you what is the point of using stripped strings function?  What it adds to our code why not use ```get.text(strip=True)``` like others?

Comment: [`Stripped strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) - Simply because the structure allows it and can save individual steps - To get started and to understand what is happening in detail, it would also be legitimate to make individual selections and then extract the text from these via `get_text()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your Category column only has `None` values is because the elements that `soup.select("#serviceList tr:has(td)")` finds do NOT have the css attribute `data-filter-table-category-id`. The elements its finding are like this:

```
<tr class="">
 <td class="service-id">
  7365
 </td>
 <td class="service-name">
  YouTube - Subscribers ~ Max 120k ~  30D ~ 500-2k/days ~ [  - , �                   ]
 </td>
 <td class="service-rate">
  $4.80
 </td>
 <td class="service-min-max">
  100 / 120000
 </td>
 <td class="">
  <span class="badge gurantee">
   Refill 30 days
  </span>
 </td>
 <td class="average-time ser-id-7365">
  63 hours 40 minutes
 </td>
 <td class="text-right service-description">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-target="#description-7365" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <i class="mdi mdi-information">
   </i>
   Details
  </a>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="description7365Label" class="modal fade text-left" id="description-7365" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="description7365Label">
       YouTube - Subscribers ~ Max 120k ~  30D ~ 500-2k/days ~ [  - ,                 ]'s Description
      </h5>
      <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
       <span aria-hidden="true">
        ×
       </span>
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p style="line-height: 20px;">
       Link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYhvmzYNxCAGBaMhnsk69kg
       <br/>
       Start: Instant - 0 hrs
       <br/>
       Speed: 500-2k/day
       <br/>
       Refill: 30 days
       <br/>
       <br/>
       Drop: 0- 5% drop.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
       <i class="mdi mdi-close">
       </i>
       Close
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

From what I have deciphered from your post, you want to create a table similar to the ones on bulkfollows.com except for 3 main differences:

1. Your table will be the aggregate of the tables on the website
2. Your table will contain an additional column--Category--(which will contain the Service category IDs???)
3. Your table's Description column will contain the text hidden behind the purple Details buttons.

Yourself or someone else can figure out the precise solution to your problem; I will merely point you in the right direction.

#### General Approach:

**First** collect of the HTML elements that make up the individual tables. These are the div elements with the classes `col-lg-12 mb-3 ser-row`.

```
tables = soup.select('div.col-lg-12.mb-3.ser-row')
```

**Secondly** iterate over the list of elements.

**Then** in each iteration:

1. use the same logic in your code. That is, create a dictionary with the current table's column names and values as the keys and values, respectively.
2. Get the value of the css attribute data-filter-table-category-id. Create a new key, Category, and assign the css attr's value to it.
3. Combine the dict's into a DataFrame (as you did in your code).

Comment: thanks for your time and effort !